# How to restart a multithreaded C++ program inside the code?

Tags: c++, multithreading

as i describe in the header I would like to have in a thread an if statement which is checked every 1 minute and if it is true restart the whole programm.. Any suggestions?

```
void* checkThread(void* arg)
 {
   if(statement)
    //restart procedure
   sleep(60);
 }

 int main()
{
 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, checkThread, main_object);
 pthread_create();
 pthread_create();
}
```

Comment: what is your platform?

Comment: Well firstly because I am using an external library I tried to call stop() and then start() of the main object of this library that I use in this checking thread that I want to have but didn"t work. Then I thought if my statement is true to join threads, free memory etc, and then create again everything of my programm but this also is not a solution I suppose to do it in a thread. So that's all up to now..

Comment: I am writing a C++ project in Eclipse under CentOs.

Comment: You should edit your question and include that information. Also get familiar with [Short Self Contained Correct/Compilable Examples - SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so you have an idea of how to cobble up the code to include it as well.

Comment: You can do this sort of thing using the OS itself. I believe /etc/init* (maybe inittab?) can have a line added to automatically restart a daemon process if it crashes (returns a non-zero value from main).

Comment: Yes you are correct this can happen using the OS, I know it but I would prefer to do it inside the code. Thank you anyway but if still someone else knows another way I would be glad. Also I am gonna try to edit the first post with a code snippet.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going for the nuke-it-from-orbit approach (i.e. you don't want to trust your code to do a controlled shutdown reliably), then having the kill-and-auto-relaunch mechanism inside the same process space as the other code is not a very robust approach.  For example, if one of the other threads were to crash, it would take your auto-restart-thread down with it.

A more fail-safe approach would be to have your auto-restart-thread launch all of the other code in a sub-process (via fork(); calling exec() is allowable but not necessary in this case).  After 60 seconds, the parent process can kill the child process it created (by calling kill() on the process ID that fork() returned) and then launch a new one.

The advantage of doing it this way is that the separating of memory spaces protects your relauncher-code from any bugs in the rest of the code, and the killing of the child process means that the OS will handle all the cleanup of memory and other resources for you, so there is less of a worry about things like memory or file-handle leaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "nice" way to do it, you set a flag, and then politely wait for the threads to finish, before relaunching everything.

```
main_thread() {
  do {
    kill_and_restart_everything = false;
    // create your threads.
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, checkThread, main_object);
    pthread_create(&thread2, ...);
    pthread_create(&thread3, ...);
    // wait for your threads.
    pthread_join(thread1, nullptr);
    pthread_join(thread2, nullptr);
    pthread_join(thread3, nullptr);
  } while (kill_and_restart_everything);
}

void* checkThread(void* arg) {
  while (! kill_and_restart_everything) {
    if(statement)
      kill_and_restart_everything = true;
    else
      sleep(60);
  }
}

void* workerThread(void* arg) {
  // do stuff.  periodically check
  if (kill_and_restart_everything) {
    // terminate this thread early.
    // do it cleanly too, release any resources, etc (RAII is your friend here).
    return nullptr;
  }
  // do other stuff, remember to have that check happen fairly regularly.
}
```

This way, whenever `if(statement)` is true, it will set a boolean that can be used to tell each thread to shut down.  Then the program waits for each thread to finish, and then starts it all over again.

Downsides:  If you're using any global state, that data will not be cleaned up and can cause problems for you.  If a thread doesn't check your signal, you could be waiting a looooong time.

If you want to kill everything (nuke it from orbit) and restart, you could simply wrap this program in a shell script (which can then detect whatever condition you want, kill -9 the program, and relaunch it).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exec` system call to restart the process from the start of the program.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know the exec seems interesting and that can do the work. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two parts:

Part1: one thread that checks for the statement and sets a boolean to true when you need to restart the program
This is the "checker" thread

Part2: one thread that computes what you want:
this will "relaunch" the program as long as needed
This "relaunch" consists in a big loop
In the loop:

- creates a thread that will actually execute your programme (the task you want to be executed)
- ends this taks when the boolean is set to true
- creates another thread to replace then one that is terminated

The main of your program consists in launching the "checker" and the "relauncher"

Tell me if you have any questions/remarks I can detail or add some code